# Cannot fetch record from local data storage

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using LSAdapter for my emberjs app and I am not able to fetch data from local storage.

I have confirmed that there are records in my local storage for a model called `user`. From console, I see:

```
{"id":"t10v0","email":"d@s.com","firstName":"d","lastName":"s","password":"be0a9c3fe6609764f3db07c5b4f4d689c19ea739f32ef098c9bde75e67a4119ce50e8604c93c47c9796b224139d740954672c5aa2c3de6313e9ddf09ddbf66da"}
```

For some reason, however, in my controller, when I do

```
var allUsers = this.store.all('user');
console.log(allUsers.get('length'));
```

I get 0 for length. I have even tried:

```
var existingUsers = this.store.filter('user', function(user) {
                return !user.get('d@s.com');
            });

console.log(existingUsers.get('length'));
```

And I still get 0....

Anyone here knows how to wor with existing data in localstorage through ember-data?

Comment: did you try `this.store.find('user')`? `store#all` returns records already loaded into the store (i.e. after the adapter has requested & returned them).

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `this.store.find('user')` which will return all 'user' models.